# Need to remove whitespace from file using regular expression

Tags: regex, vi

I have a huge file around half a gig and the file has records shown below:

```
44     ,1577,23GRE                       ,GREASE THE ENGINE
44     ,1577,23GRE                       ,GREASE THE ENGINE
44     ,1577,24GRE                       ,GREASE THE WHEELS
```

I want to remove white spaces between the the commas and whitespaces after content "GREASE THE ENGINE" and convert the file as shown below using vi:

```
"44","1577","23GRE","GREASE THE ENGINE"
"44","1577","23GRE","GREASE THE ENGINE"
"44","1577","24GRE","GREASE THE WHEELS"
```

I tried removing whitespaces by giving a command :1,$s/ //g  This removes all the whitespace and renders the file as shown below which defeats the purpose. I want GREASE THE ENGINE with spaces.

```
44,1577,23GRE,GREASETHEENGINE
44,1577,23GRE,GREASETHEENGINE
44,1577,24GRE,GREASETHEWHEELS
```

Appreciate any or all help.

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to match trailing whitespace with the pattern `/(\s+)(?:[,\n]|$)/g`

Comment: I get no match, if i use (\s+)(?:[,\n]|$)/g

Comment: I can't say how vi handles these kinds of things, that's just a generic perl regex pattern that will match any amount of whitespace followed by a comma, newline, or EOF while not matching said delimiter (comma, newline, eof).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this substitute command in `vi`:

```
:1,$s/ *,/,/g
:1,$s/ *$//
:1,$s/,/","/g
```

First we replace trailing spaces then replace all spaces followed by `,` to a single `,`. Finally we match each field that is not a comma and quote them.

`[[:blank:]]` will match a space or tab.

For your input it gives:

```
"44","1577","23GRE","GREASE THE ENGINE"
"44","1577","23GRE","GREASE THE ENGINE"
"44","1577","24GRE","GREASE THE WHEELS"
```

Comment: With winvi (windows version of vi), it is not working.

Comment: I get no match for :%s/[[:blank:]]\+,/,/g

Comment: We need to remove spaces preceding the ,

Comment: This worked for most part except for trailing spaces. I can fix that my way, by putting first a comma (,) to end and then using your command :s/ *,/,/g

Comment: I have not accepted as answer because it has not removed trailing spaces. This is output of Hue, HIVE editor and has removed all spaces prior to comma, except last one. Not sure, why. I am going to continue this  little later

Comment: Agreed, it works. I am going to put all steps and let you know. You can put that and I will mark it as answered by you. That way somebody can just use what you told, since I have validated. Give me 10 mins

Comment: 1. First remove spaces preceding comma (,) by `:1,$s/ *,/,/g` which means from first line to last replace spaces followed by comma with comma globally

Comment: 2. Remove trailing space if any by `:1,$s/ *$//g`

Comment: 3. Put quote in first and last characters by giving 2 commands `:1,$s/^/"` and `:1,$s/$/"` and replace comma (,) with quote comma quote ("," ) by command `:1,$s/,/","/g`  Hey Anubhav, If rewrite your answer putting steps  1,2 & 3, I will accept

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

```
%s/\s\+\([,$]\)/"\1"/g
%s/^/"/g
%s/$/"/g
```

- Remove any sequence of white space characters (white space, tab, etc.) before a comma or the end of line;
- Add `"` at the beginning of every line
- Add `"` at the end of every line

If you had an empty line at the end of the file, you will end up with a line of  `""` which is easy to delete.